# Loop to obtain infinite ArrayList/Lists from database table

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code to create an ArrayList from a database table, and split it into 3 separate ArrayLists:

```
    table = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from tab1";
    ResultSet rs = table.executeQuery(sql);
    int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

    ArrayList<String> tempTable = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int i = 1;
        while(i<=columns)
        {
            tempTable.add(rs.getString(i++));
        }
    }
    ArrayList<String> tempTable1 = new ArrayList<String>(tempTabe.subList(0, 9));
    String tableonLine = tempTable1.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-:.,]", " ");
    System.out.println("Sublist 1: "+tableonLine);

    ArrayList<String> tempTable2 = new ArrayList<String>(tempTable.subList(9, 18));
    String tableoneLine2 = tempTable2.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-:.,]", " ");
    System.out.println("Sublist 2: "+tableoneLine2);

    ArrayList<String> tempTable3 = new ArrayList<String>(tempTable.subList(18, 27));
    String tableoneLine3 = tempTable3.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-:.,]", " ");
    System.out.println("Sublist 3: "+tableoneLine3);
```

My issue is that whilst the code works for splitting each row in turn when I know the number of rows in the table, I need to make it infinitely expandable so that the application will obtain each row in turn, and send these to a 2-dimensional String array. Can anyone think of a solution?

Comment: arraylist is dynamic so where you are facing issue??

Comment: Get the arraylist size and divide it by 3 then you can do the same with the sizes.

Comment: @PrashantMy first time using ArrayLists and not sure of their capabilities. I need to send each row (9 columns) to an array for editing

Comment: @Kumar Tanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: What is the rule for splitting ? is it to divide the total number of rows by 3 ? can you post an example of data you have in the table and what you want to achieve as result ?

Comment: @AbbéRésina
There are 9 columns:
id|Username|Password|UserType|Full Name|DOB|Location|Recorded

a pseudo-table with each row correctly displayed

Comment: your problem is like if you are having 1000 rows of data you want to split it in three separate arraylist??

Comment: @Prashant no no, I have a database table. I need to split this into separate rows, and into an array of arrays, where each column, and each row is an element. There are 9 columns total, with up to 100 rows

Comment: now i got but not sure you are asking the same. you will have one array of columns then 1 column will be an array. array of arrays.

Comment: @Prashant That's pretty much it. The application is just an exercise (severely over-complicated at that) and will have the data from the table manipulated in the array and will then upload this to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want is an `ArrayList` of fixed length `String[]` arrays that you read your `ResultSet` into.  You know the width of your data - it's returned from the SQL query in `columns`.  But you want it to go on for as many rows as you like, right?  You can do this with an `ArrayList` by just keep adding members.  For the members themselves - they can just be fixed width (in your case 9) arrays.

So - alter the code where you deal with each row:

```
//Note - changed temp table to a List of String[] members,
//replacing one long list of Strings.
ArrayList<String[]> tempTable = new ArrayList<String[]>();

//Turn each row into a String[] and then add it to the list
while(rs.next())
{
    int i = 1; 
    String[] rowData = new String[columns];
    while(i<=columns)
    {
        rowData[i] = rs.getString(i++);
    }
    tempTable.add(rowData);
}
```

***Note*** - it's pretty unusual to start i at 1 - are you sure you don't want to start it at 0? Java indexes into arrays and lists are zero based.

Then, once this has completed, you have an ArrayList whose `size()` is the number of rows you have and whose members are fixed length `String` arrays.  To turn this into a 2D String array becomes pretty simple:

```
String[][] outArr = new String[tempTable.size()][columns];
int i = 0;
for (rowArr : tempTable)
{
    System.arraycopy(rowArr,0,outArr[i++],0,columns);
}
```

You now have the 2D string array you wanted in `outArr`.

---

***Note*** If the data had variable width rows - you'd need to use the `List` of `List`s approach [proposed by @NickJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738341/838992).  The principle is the same - it just means that your code to put the results into a 2D string array is harder, because you have to find the maximum width row to dimension the `String[][]`.  This is not needed when dealing with an SQL query.

***Final Note*** Your approach is fine - if a little hard to read.  If you're keen to carry on with that way of doing things - you can generate your sublists as follows (replacing the code where you do it one by one).  It's a somewhat convoluted way of doing things, though.  I've also made it fill an `outArr` 2D array as based on comments this seems to be key to requirements

```
// get the dimensions of your 2D array from your tempTable size
// which will be columns * rows long
String[][] outArr = new String[tempTable.size()/columns][columns]

for (int subStart = 0; subStart < tempTable.size(); subStart += columns)
{
    ArrayList<String> tempTable1 = new ArrayList<String>(
                                     tempTable.subList(subStart, subStart+columns));
    int rownum = subStart / columns;

    // each "tempTable1" represents a row in the table - write
    // this element by element to your 2D String array.
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        outArr[rownum][i] = tempTable1.get(i);
    }

    String tableonLine = tempTable1.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-:.,]", " ");

    System.out.println("Sublist "+ rownum + ": "+tableonLine);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! One final question and i'll be set to go (feeling really stupid):

How can I get the result from my convoluted method into a 2D-array in a way I can have another method find a string and edit it?

The application spec requires me to edit elements of the array then over-write the database from where they originate (i had the the thought of dropping the database then re-creating it)

Comment: It's difficult. I can show you, but I'm curious why you would want to go from this method to a 2D array (hard), rather than using the `ArrayList<String[]>` method (easy).  I could understand if you just wanted to print.  Is it the `replaceAll` bit that you're still keen to do?  Have you already got the "another method to find a string and edit it" code for a `String[][]`?  Taking a `String[][]` and using it to produce a batched UPDATE SQL query is really a different question - the answer would get too long if we did that here too. If you need that - ask another question and link it.

Comment: A thought on the updating - if you need to do an update query, you need to be able to identify the row you're updating - have the rows got some kind of guaranteed unique ID (UID) that won't be changed in your code before you write the result back.

Comment: Simple: I am not allowed to use ArrayLists for this application. Ideally I would just edit the database directly, but unfortunately my mentor had other ideas. With regards to UID's, the row ID isn't edited in the slightest, only the user's name, DOB and location are manually changed, where the Age is calculated on DOB change.

Comment: OK - but your original code used an ArrayList as a temporary thing.  Can't you use the two snippets I provided to get to the point where you have `outArr` (a `String[][]`)?  The convoluted bit I mentioned was where you put all the rows into a very long `ArrayList` and then take them out again 9 by 9 by 9.  Once you've got the String[][], you can alter any element of it.  I'm kinda feeling that you're stuck with a horrible design pattern, though.  Manipulating `date` (DOB) and `int` (age) types as strings is hard to get right and prone to mistakes...

Comment: However - if you've got the code to manipulate the `String[][]` in such a way as to alter the right row and column - putting it back into the database isn't too hard if theres a UID.  Ask a new question e.g. "How can I turn `String[][]` into an SQL update query?" with some details (e.g. cols that are changing, first row is header etc) and I can look to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus-far, it might take me some time to get the other question up & running as i have a mountain of code to sift through

Comment: No probs.  Good luck.  I've added a tiny bit of code to the last example if you do want to make a `String[][]` from your original.  Put a comment here if / when you ask the question about update.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a List of Lists:

```
List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Each element of the outer list of a row, each element of the inner list is a value. Then your loop would be something like:

```
while(rs.next() {
  List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
  int i=1;
  while (i<=columns) {
    row.add(rs.getString(i);
  }
  rows.add(row);
}
```

That should work :)

Comment: I tried to SYSOU this to verify and it only recovered the very first element, any reason for this?

Comment: What are you SYSOU ing exactly?

Comment: inspect the content of each row using a loop: for (String data:row) System.out.println(data);

Comment: I feel really stupid but that didn't work... What am I doing wrong? =(

List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
   while(rs.next())
   {
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i=1;
    while(i<=columns)
    {
     row.add(rs.getString(i));
    }
    rows.add(row);
    
    for(String data: row)
    {
     System.out.println("ROW: "+data);
    }
   }

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, forgot to increment i: row.add(rs.getString(i++));

Comment: I got that to work, but I need it so that it will populate a two-dimensional String array with the column name on top and the corresponding below in a form of pseudo table. Is this possible?

Comment: Once the `List` of `List`s is populated - you can just use the [`ArrayList.toArray()`](]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method. Make a big array based on the list sized e.g. `String[][] outArr = new String[rows.size()][rows.get(0).size()]`.  Then, in a loop, call `toArray` on each row and copy it into the corresponding row in `outArr` using `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was actually much simpler than I first thought:

**Solved**

```
public static String[][] TableToArray() throws SQLException
{
    String[][] dbTable = null;
    table = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from Java_Test_Profiles";
    ResultSet rs = table.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.last();
    int rowNumb = rs.getRow();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnS = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    dbTable= new String[rowNumb][columnS];

    int i=0;
    while(rs.next() && i<rowNumb)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnS;i++)
        {
            dbTable[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return dbTable; 
}
```